# Typescript type BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

What's kind of type I should use when using `beforeinstallprompt` event?

I tried `BeforeInstallPromptEvent` type, but gave me an error:

```
export class PwaService {
  //promptEvent: BeforeInstallPromptEvent;
  promptEvent;
  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate, platform: PlatformService) {
    if(platform.isBrowser()){
      swUpdate.available.subscribe(event =>  {
        /*if (askUserToUpdate()) {
          window.location.reload();
        }*/
      });
      window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', event => {
        this.promptEvent = event;
      });
    }
  }

  install(): void {
    if(this.promptEvent){
      this.promptEvent.prompt();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm reviewing [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) on the `BeforeInstallPromptEvent` and it doesn't appear to me that the Promise returned by `userChoice` provides an Object as it's argument. However, [Google Developers - Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) documents the Type to be as the above describes. If I can find some clarity to the matter I'll be sure to document it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [BeforeInstallPromptEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) is a non-standard Web API and currently only supported by Chrome and Android. I'm not even sure whether Google considers it stable yet, but in either case I wouldn't expect to see an official type definition in the TypeScript DOM library any time soon.

However you can define the type yourself, e.g. in a *.d.ts file*. I use the definition below (comments from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent)), which seems to be accurate enough in Chrome 68.

```
/**
 * The BeforeInstallPromptEvent is fired at the Window.onbeforeinstallprompt handler
 * before a user is prompted to "install" a web site to a home screen on mobile.
 *
 * @deprecated Only supported on Chrome and Android Webview.
 */
interface BeforeInstallPromptEvent extends Event {

  /**
   * Returns an array of DOMString items containing the platforms on which the event was dispatched.
   * This is provided for user agents that want to present a choice of versions to the user such as,
   * for example, "web" or "play" which would allow the user to chose between a web version or
   * an Android version.
   */
  readonly platforms: Array<string>;

  /**
   * Returns a Promise that resolves to a DOMString containing either "accepted" or "dismissed".
   */
  readonly userChoice: Promise<{
    outcome: 'accepted' | 'dismissed',
    platform: string
  }>;

  /**
   * Allows a developer to show the install prompt at a time of their own choosing.
   * This method returns a Promise.
   */
  prompt(): Promise<void>;

}
```

Comment: Don't forget ```interface WindowEventMap {
        "beforeinstallprompt": BeforeInstallPromptEvent;
    }```
Might also need to put this in a `declare global {}` block.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: it should not be marked as @deprecated since it is still supported by newest versions of all browsers (except iOS Safari and Firefox)

Answer (score 18):

Improvement to the accepted answer: you also need to add a key into `WindowEventMap`:

```
interface BeforeInstallPromptEvent extends Event {
  readonly platforms: string[];
  readonly userChoice: Promise<{
    outcome: "accepted" | "dismissed";
    platform: string;
  }>;
  prompt(): Promise<void>;
}

declare global {
  interface WindowEventMap {
    beforeinstallprompt: BeforeInstallPromptEvent;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {}); // e is now typed
```

Note the `declare global {}` is a wrapper for typing global stuff in your code. You could also do it in an ambient file where no import / export keyword exists, then no need for the wrapper. But it's a good practice to put related code in the same file.

Comment: nice improvement.  this is necessary if you are using the `strictFunctionTypes` flag

Answer (score 0):

Another addition to the interface could be to extract the `userChoice` as a type. An promise object of the same shape is also returned by `prompt()`:

```
type UserChoice = Promise<{
  outcome: 'accepted' | 'dismissed';
  platform: string;
}>;

interface BeforeInstallPromptEvent extends Event {
  readonly platforms: string[];
  readonly userChoice: UserChoice;
  prompt(): Promise<UserChoice>;
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent/prompt#return_value